# Auto relationship in adonis.js /node.js, how can i show only one property?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have one table users that have a auto-relationship, so, 1 user must be updated by himself.

So, i make this migration:

```
class UserSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('users', (table) => {
      table.increments() /
      table.string('username').notNullable().unique()
      table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('users')
  }
}
```

In this query i need the name of the user that update one user.
So i try this query in my controller:

```
async index({request}) {
    const page = request.input('page')
    const pageSize = request.input('pageSize')
    const users = await User
        .query()
        .with('user')
        .paginate(page, pageSize)
    return users.toJSON()
}
```

As you can see in this json, i'm receiving an array of the user, there's a way to receive only the name of the user_id?

```
{"total":"1","perPage":10,"page":1,"lastPage":1,"data":[{"id":1,"username":"admin","user_id":1,"created_at":"2019-10-28 11:17:29","updated_at":"2019-10-28 14:27:22","user":{"id":1,"username":"admin", "user_id":1,"created_at":"2019-10-28 11:17:29","updated_at":"2019-10-28 14:27:22"}}]}
```

How i can catch the name of the user that make the update by the user_id?

I put this in my Model:

```
  user () {
    return this.hasOne('App/Models/User')
  }
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your code example. It seems that in the users table you have a reference to a column in the same table which is not something you want

Comment: I put this reference because one user can be updated by himself...

Comment: My return is correct, but instead of put a object in the json, i need some the username of the user_id referenced... i don't know if it is possible

Comment: I understand now, then you won't need the `.with()` statement cause you are making a circular reference basically to the same model. If you remove that and change the controller code to use the `id` of the authenticated user I think that would achieve what you want

Comment: I don't think idea of how i can do this: "change the controller code to use the id of the authenticated user" i think i need something like: {"total":"1","perPage":10,"page":1,"lastPage":1,"data":[{"id":1,"username":"admin","user_id":1,"created_at":"2019-10-28 11:17:29","updated_at":"2019-10-28 14:27:22", username_updated: "admin"}]